# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar after updaring to v7.AppCompat Version 23.3 Xamarin Forms 2.2.0.31

Tags: xamarin

I am creating a Xamarin Forms Project and using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar with FormsAppCompatActivity. The code I'm posting below was working with Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat Version: 23.0.1.3

But after I upgraded to 23.3.0 this has started throwing Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.toolbar exception.

Here is my code for MainActivity

```
[Activity(Label = "AppMob.Client", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
            FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this,bundle);                        
            GoogleAnalyticsHelper.GetGASInstance().Initialize_NativeGAS(Application.Context);  //For GA initialization
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
}
```

This is my code for Resource.Layout.toolbar

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

I have updated Xamarin Forms to 2.2.0.31

Dependencies for this version of Xamarin Forms mention:

```
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0) 
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0) 
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0) 
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0) 
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0)
```

it should thus be compatible with 23.3.

Answer (score 3):

May you don't declare theme of layout in your activity.cs
you must add this to youractivity.cs:

```
Theme = "@style/MyThemesss"
```

Answer (score 2):

Once I had your problem and I did the below steps to solve it :

- Call `RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeature.Notiltle)` in the first line of `OnCreate(Bundle bundle)` and above everything else and double check if you did remove the ActionBar .
- Clean solution , Remove all support library dependencies , change toolbar Id and restart Visual Studio (or Xamarin Studio) Then re-add support libraries and build solution. (sometimes the cause of error is caching or big piles of other junk files in solution .)
- Consider not using `"?attr/colorPrimary"` instead call the color resource directly.

and after all if you could post your style xml file and main layout ,i would helped more efficiently.

Comment: On the third point: Do you mean to use "@color/colorPrimaryDark" instead of "?attr/colorPrimary"? The only difference is by calling the resource directly your app avoids looking for that value in all Resources/values files, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This error is resolved as follows.

You need to update Xamarin Forms for that solution. In the NuGet Package.
The package that says CardView too.

Then you should do clean, rebuild.

This will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, 
probably you may delete some option in  tag like "app:layout_scrollFlags" that not supported in api 21, if all options are ok, delete "?attr" values and put their real value instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that I had written android.suport.v7.widget.Toolbar ("suport" with one letter "p" instead of "support")

And it worked immediately when I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning solution and restarting VS helped me.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging Xamarin project, go to Debug->Windows->Exception Settings
Under Common Language Runtime Exceptions uncheck System.Exception